# Should I flag a question that is not detailed?

Tags: discussion

I've been seeing a lot of questions recently that are just not detailed enough to know what to answer and I was wondering if that's something I should flag a question for or not?
And if so then what should I flag it as?

Comment: Is it **so** un-detailed that you need to bother a moderator about it?

Comment: Flagging is not appropriate.  Voting to close is probably appropriate; leaving a comment say that the question is not detailed enough may be appropriate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Low rep users can only flag to close, rather than voting to close.

Comment: When you get to 125 rep, just downvote; there is no rep cost to downvote a question. And at 50 rep you can leave a comment asking the OP for clarification. If you feel you must flag, use one of the standard close flags like "unclear what you're asking", which does not require attention from a diamond moderator. Only send a message to a moderator if the site appears to be burning down.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If a question does not have enough information to be answerable you can vote/flag the question for closure using the "Unclear what you're asking" close reason.